# Fading out a menu's opacity with css transitions

Tags: html, css, animation, coffeescript, sass

My problem is this:

I want to have a menu fade in and out of visibility when a user hovers over its parent container. I also want to do the animation with css only. Here's the code as it stands:

**HTML**

```
<div class="color-dropdown">
    <div class="title">
        <h4>Red</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="options">
        <ul class="colors">
            <li>Red</li>
            <li>Blue</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.color-dropdown {
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;

    .options {
        opacity: 0;

        /*
            The problem - This css transition never 
            gets seen on mouseout, most likely because 
            overflow is immediately hidden.
        */
        transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    }

    &.expanded {
        overflow: visible;
        .options {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**Coffeescript**

```
colorDropdown = $('.color-dropdown')
title         = $('.title h4')
colors        = $('.colors li')

colorDropdown.hover ->
    # Fade in the options
    colorDropdown.addClass 'expanded'
, ->
    # Fade out - Broken!
    colorDropdown.removeClass 'expanded'

colors.click ->
    # Fade out - Broken!
    colorDropdown.removeClass 'expanded'

    # Change the current color
    title.text $(this).text()

    # CSS bounce animation (using animate.css here)
    title.addClass 'animated bounce'
    setTimeout ->
        title.removeClass 'animated bounce'
    , 1000
```

[I've made a jsfiddle here so that you can easily see the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/taylorlapeyre/FH5Nr/).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I'm interpreting your scss comments correctly, the transition fade isn't being triggered and thus fade's out with no transition?

Comment: Sorry, transitions in CSS currently do not work in conjunction with: background gradients, opacity. You cannot do this in CSS.

Comment: I'm a little confused @setek. In my jsfiddle, the opacity transition is working fine. It's the fact that the overflow is immediately hidden that is preventing the fade out to be shown. Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: @TaylorLapeyre oops my mistake, sorry, it does seem to work. Must just be background gradients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `overflow: hidden` <-> `overflow: visible` change ... when you remove `.expanded` you will not see the transition on the child if the overflow on the parent jumps back to hidden.

You can fix this with using a transition on `visibility` of the child (`.options`) element.

Something like this (with `transition-delay` set to `0s`) perhaps:

```
.color-dropdown {
    height: 60px;
    overflow: visible;
    .options {
        opacity: 0;
        visibility:hidden;
        transition: visibility 0s linear 0.2s, opacity 0.2s linear;
    }

    &.expanded .options {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility:visible;
        transition-delay: 0s;
    }
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FH5Nr/9/)

More on this can be found here: http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337